Checking if "alt" (specifically) key is held in WinUI
Not a duplicate of this question.
I'm trying to check if the "alt" key is held down while listening to an element's KeyDown event like so:
    private void AutoSuggestBox_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (/* alt is pressed and */ e.Key == VirtualKey.Down)
        {
            (sender as AutoSuggestBox).IsSuggestionListOpen = true;
        }
    }

Per the linked question above, I know you can use InputKeyboardSourc.GetKeyStateForCurrentThread(key).HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down), but the key problem is: VirtualKey doesn't seem to have a definition for the alt key (nor does VirutalKeyModifiers).
I am aware that this likely means that one should avoid using the alt key in such a way, however I don't have any choice in the requirement.

this method can be used from the Keyboard class
private void AutoSuggestBox_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var altKeyState = (CoreVirtualKeyStates) Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.Keyboard.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.LeftMenu); 

    if (altKeyState.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) && e.Key == VirtualKey.Down)
    {
        (sender as AutoSuggestBox).IsSuggestionListOpen = true;
    }
}


Keyboard class from the Windows.System namespace can help !
